# I have a conflict libraries

Tags: javascript

I have a library conflict problem. My code is like so in template...

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write(unescape(\'%3Cscript src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E\'))</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="' . $settings['theme'] . '/scripts/qs.js"></script>

    ';
    }.............
```

And in the qs.js file I have the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.sp-body img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
        alt: $(this).attr('src'),
        src: smf_default_theme_url + '/images/loading.gif'
    });
});
$("body").on("click", ".sp-head", function(event){
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("unfolded")) {
        $this.removeClass("unfolded");
        $this.next().slideUp("fast");
        $this.next().addClass("folded");
    } else {
        $this.addClass("unfolded");
        $this.next().slideDown("fast");
        $this.next().removeClass("folded");
    }
    c = $this.parent().children('.sp-body');
    c.find('img').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('alt'));
    });
});
$("body").on("click", ".sp-foot", function(event){
    $this = $(this).closest("div.sp-body").prev();
    if ($this.hasClass("unfolded")) {
        $this.removeClass("unfolded");
        $this.next().slideUp("fast");
        $this.next().addClass("folded");
    }
});
```

});

the mistake is in "$(...).on is not a function" -> $("body").on("click", ".sp-head", function(event){

The problem is in the conflict between libraries. I have looked at the non-conflict mode but I can't get it to work for me, how can I get it to work?

Thanks!!

Comment: are you having an issue with trying to load two different versions of jquery?

Comment: @JaromandaX in one i load "<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write(unescape(\'%3Cscript src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E\'))</script>" in other i load jquery.1.3.2.min.js

Comment: why are you escaping the `'` in  `unescape(\'.....\')`? makes no sense - should just be `unescape('.....')` - so you want 1.7.1 and 1.3.2 ... and how exactly are you attempting non-conflict mode? seems you aren't at all in the code you posted - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Why on earth do you have a `document.write` just to load another library? Just load the jQuery you need: It already skips loading itself if it sees another jQuery has already been loaded in, no need to check whether it exists and then if it doesn't, use a low-level byte stream function that is [really not meant to be used anymore](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript).

Comment: @JaromandaX The scripts are loaded in 2 different but communicated templates. The \ is necessary because it is in php. I've tried adding <script> $.noConflict()... or jQuery.noConflic...</script>